How do I connect 2 data sets in excel using dynamic functions?
I am building a report for sales people and need to connect two data sets with dynamic functions.
Data set 1 is targets, but each individual could have multiple records (e.g. if they have a different leader throughout year. e.g. person a has had 3 leaders. I also need ability to include or exclude records based on selection in the report:

I then need to connect this data with Data set 2, which shows the volumes by account for the accounts signed along with who signed it. I would need the ability to also include or exclude certain records, and some accounts could be split between 2 individuals (account y)

The end result would need to be target and sales volume per leader based on when that leader had volume rolling up to them along the lines of:

as an example, I have the following that pivots the data for targets:
=LET(
  names,  UNIQUE(B2:B5),
  namesWithYes, FILTER(B2:B5, P2:P5="yes"),
  TargetWithYes, BYROW(FILTER(C2:O5,P2:P5="yes"),LAMBDA(α,SUM(CHOOSECOLS(DROP(α,,1),--TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(α,1),","))))),
  Targets,  MMULT(--(names=TRANSPOSE(namesWithYes) ), TargetWithYes),
  IF( {1,0}, names, Targets )
)


I'm not sure how you got to your expected output, with some FILTER I can get the results based on leader 2, but it's unclear how you got to your own results.

sorry. typo for target for leader 1. it should be 99 instead of 68

as an example I have the following that pivots for the target:
=LET(
names,  UNIQUE(B2:B5),
namesWithYes, FILTER(B2:B5, P2:P5="yes"),
TargetWithYes, BYROW(FILTER(C2:O5,P2:P5="yes"),LAMBDA(α,SUM(CHOOSECOLS(DROP(α,,1),--TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(α,1),","))))),
Targets,  MMULT(--(names=TRANSPOSE(namesWithYes) ), TargetWithYes),
IF( {1,0}, names, Targets )
)

Try [edit] into the actual queston, comments will be removed over time. (I can't edit it in for you at this moment, otherwise I'd happy to help)

sorry. I am new to all this. Thank you :-)

If understood correctly, you want to achieve the volumes, if so then could use the following formula:


=LET(
     names, UNIQUE(B2:B5),
     namesWithYes, FILTER(B2:B5, P2:P5="yes"),
     TargetWithYes, BYROW(FILTER(C2:O5,P2:P5="yes"),LAMBDA(α,SUM(INDEX(α,--TEXTSPLIT(@α,",")+1)))),
     Targets, MMULT(--(names=TOROW(namesWithYes) ), TargetWithYes),
     Volumes, MAP(names, LAMBDA(α, LET(δ, FILTER(HSTACK(A2:A5,D2:O5),α=B2:B5,""),
              SUM(BYROW(δ, LAMBDA(ε, SUM(IF((INDEX(ε,1)=A8:A11)*(DROP(ε,,1)>0)*(O8:O11="Yes"),C8:N11,0)))))))),
     HSTACK(names, Targets,Volumes))



If using tables is feasible for your need, you could try this variant (thanks for the question, by the way :)

=LET(
    targetWithYes, tblTarget[include] = "yes",
    volumeWithYes, tblVolume[include] = "yes",
    delim, ",",
    row_delim, ";",
    include_col, LAMBDA(col_headers, csv_incl,
        ISNUMBER(
            XMATCH(
                col_headers,
                TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(csv_incl, ","))
            )
        )
    ),
    name_months_for_leader, LAMBDA(l,
        FILTER(
            HSTACK(tblTarget[name], tblTarget[Months]),
            tblTarget[Leader] = l
        )
    ),
    sum_volume, LAMBDA(name_months,
        SUMPRODUCT(
            tblVolume[[1]:[12]] * volumeWithYes *
                (tblVolume[name] = INDEX(name_months, 1, 1)) *
                include_col(
                    tblVolume[[#Headers],[1]:[12]],
                    INDEX(name_months, 1, 2)
                )
        )
    ),
    u_leader, UNIQUE(
        FILTER(tblTarget[Leader], targetWithYes)
    ),
    leader_target_volume, TEXTJOIN(
        row_delim,
        ,
        BYROW(
            u_leader,
            LAMBDA(l,
                LET(
                    sum_target, SUMPRODUCT(
                        tblTarget[[1]:[12]] *
                            (tblTarget[Leader] = l) *
                            targetWithYes
                    ),
                    sum_volume, SUM(
                        BYROW(
                            name_months_for_leader(l),
                            sum_volume
                        )
                    ),
                    TEXTJOIN(
                        delim,
                        ,
                        l,
                        sum_target,
                        sum_volume
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    TEXTSPLIT(leader_target_volume, delim, row_delim)
)


For the first part (Target):
=SUM(FILTER($D$2:$O$5 , ($B$2:$B$5 = A10) * ($P$2:$P$5 = "yes") ) 


Red is B2:B5, Blue is D2:O5, Green is P2:P5.
Change A10 to a cell reference, where you want to input your leader number.
Drag down for the rest of the leaders.

Thank you. However, I am trying to create array rather than dragging down formulas. e.g. for the target side I have this:
=LET(
names,  UNIQUE(B2:B5),
namesWithYes, FILTER(B2:B5, P2:P5="yes"),
TargetWithYes, BYROW(FILTER(C2:O5,P2:P5="yes"),LAMBDA(α,SUM(CHOOSECOLS(DROP(α,,1),--TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(α,1),","))))),
Targets,  MMULT(--(names=TRANSPOSE(namesWithYes) ), TargetWithYes),
IF( {1,0}, names, Targets )
)
but I would now like to connect this with data set 2 to do a similar thing with the volume. Hope this makes sense

It makes more sense now, I'm still figuring out how you get to your volume numbers though; But please include the formula you already have into your question. So we can build on that.
